# Comparing 2 insignificant p-values

Tags: statistical-significance, t-test, p-value

I've run two t-tests, and the p-value of each is `a`=`0.3` and `b`=`0.6`. I realize that that is not statistically significant. However, is it proper, or warranted, to compare these two p-values, and say that the population comprising `b` is more self-similar?

Comment: You seem to be proposing an interaction - that the difference in one group is different to the difference in the other.  Is that right?

Comment: This article may be enlightening: [*The Difference Between “Significant” and “Not Significant” is not Itself Statistically Significant*](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/research/published/signif4.pdf)

Comment: Adam_G, you might also wish to read up on [tests for equivalence](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/tost/info).

Comment: Stephen - Thanks for the article. It makes sensse, but I'm not sure how to apply it to my numbers. What should I look at?